# Swift 3 - issue to create easy request method POST (URLRequestVonvertible)

Tags: ios, json, swift3, request, alamofire

I am developing an application with Swift 3.0 and IOS 10 in Xcode 8.3.2. But I have a problem when I try to retrieve the JSON from this APIRest (http://schematic-ipsum.herokuapp.com/). What is the problem? Or how you would make the call. If you need more information regarding the code, tell me, but basically, I just want to make a call to that page to recover the biography.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4FEQ.png)

My code is this:

```
import AlamofireDomain
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper

class AuthorDAO : SimpleDAO {
    func getBiography(_ parameters: Dictionary<String, Int>,
                      callbackFuncionOK:    @escaping 
                     (PropertiesAuthorModel)->(),
                      callbackFunctionERROR: @escaping (Int,NSError)->()) {


        let ulr = NSURL( string: "http://schematic-ipsum.herokuapp.com/" as String)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:  ulr! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Constent-Type")
        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

        let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        if let json = json {
            print(json)
        }

        request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)


        Alamofire.request(request as URLRequest)
            .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    //MARK: CONTROL ON DIFERENTS KINDS OF RESPONSES ON SERVER
                    case 200:
                        if let value = response.result.value {
                            let biographyResponse = Mapper<PropertiesAuthorModel>().map(JSONObject: value)
                            callbackFuncionOK(biographyResponse!)
                        }

                    //case 400: {} ..., case 404: {} ...
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }

            //MARK: ERROR ON SERVER
            else {
                var statusCode = -1
                if let _response = response.response {
                    statusCode = _response.statusCode
                }
                var nsError: NSError = NSError(domain: Constants.UNKNOWN_HTTP_ERROR_MSG,
                                               code: Constants.UNKNOWN_HTTP_ERROR_ID,
                                               userInfo: nil)
                if let _error = response.result.error {
                    nsError = _error as NSError
                }
                callbackFunctionERROR(statusCode,nsError)
            }
        }
}
```

**And the error is: "Error Domain=Alamofire.AFError Code=4 "JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." 400"**

The problem is that it does not enter into the "if response.result.isSuccess {" because the result of the response is "nil" and goes directly to the "else". Showing the error that I have commented. Can it be because I have to send the JSON format in the httpBody request? How can I do it?

Comment: You will need to provide the code you are using to access this API. Also, post any error messages you are getting when attempting to access the REST service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have added more information like code and error .

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be more clear. "What is the problem?" isn't possible to answer without more information.

To issue HTTP request, take a look at Alamofire, an HTTP networking library written in Swift: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.request)  // original URL request
    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
    print(response.data)     // server data
    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for me not being clearer. I just want to make a request POST and with parameters ["n":2]  to the API. Where "n" is the total of results that will return the API in format JSON. But I can not in any way.

Comment: My actually code is : http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadepantalla2017-06-12alas225042.php  and it show this error "Error Domain=Alamofire.AFError Code=4 "JSON could not be serialized because of error:
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."
400" Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: You need to set the appropriate JSON to the response body.

For example:

{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "id"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "name"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "email"
    },
    "bio": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "sentence"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "avatar": {
      "type": "string",
      "ipsum": "small image"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have added more  code in my question. 
About your response, I cant set the appropiate JSON, because my code is stopped into the "else". Because my response is "nil" :( ....